# Bootstrap верстка превью с изображениями

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Необходимо сверстать небольшое превью из 6 картинок на bootstrap 4, так чтобы по высоте первая и последняя картинка занимала два блока, а по центру картинки занимали 1 блок[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На мобильных устройствах должно выглядеть так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под десктопы удалось сверстать, но под мобилки не выходит сделать центральную часть.(т.к сделано скорее всего неправильно, костыльно)

Вот так это выглядит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот что происходит с мобилками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML(упрощенный):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <img src="1.png" class="rounded img-tall"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 order-last">
        <img src="1.png" class="rounded img-tall"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">
                <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я конечно не спорю но на обычном grid это делается не так сложно да и доступность простого css гораздо облегчает понимание того "как это сделать"

Comment: Я просто весь сайт на bootstrap сверстал и скорее всего будет плохим тоном отойти от общепринятого стиля и правил в середине проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
        <img src="1.png" class="rounded img-tall"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 order-last">
        <img src="1.png" class="rounded img-tall"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-6">
                <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-6">
                    <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-6">
                <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-6 ">
                <img src="1.png" class="rounded"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)

Comment: Спасибо, здорово выручили и заодно показали как можно решать подобные проблемы

Comment: Вы сами все сделали. Просто ошиблись с классом для мобильной версии. В 3 версии col-sm-* , в 4 версии сделали просто col-*